# Prove number a of form $\frac{n^{2p} - 1}{n^2 - 1}$ is not a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, summation, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove that every number $a$  of the form $a=\frac{n^{2p} - 1}{n^2 - 1}$  is not a prime, given $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$ an odd prime $p$ with $p\not\mid n(n^2-1)$.

I know that 
$$a = \frac{n^{2p} - 1}{n^2 - 1} = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}n^{2k} $$
and my first appoach was to show that $p\mid a$  by showing that $p \mid a\cdot n \cdot (n^2-1)$, but then we have
$$a \cdot n \cdot (n^2-1) = (n^{2p}-1) \cdot n \equiv(n^2-1)\cdot n \not\equiv 0\,\, \text{ mod  } p .$$
Is there a mistake and $p \mid a$ or is there another way to prove that $a$ is not prime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{n^{2p}-1}{n^2-1}=\frac{n^p-1}{n-1}\,\frac{n^p+1}{n+1}=(n^{p-1}+n^{p-2}+\dots+n+1)(n^{p-1}-n^{p-2}+\dots-n+1).$$

Comment: [Follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573223/prove-that-an-1-equiv-1-text-mod-n-for-a-number-n-of-the-form-n)

Answer (score 4):

Because $$n^{2p}-1=(n^p-1)(n^p+1)=(n-1)(n^{p-1}+...+1)(n+1)(n^{p-1}-n^{p-2}+...+1).$$

Comment: [Follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573223/prove-that-an-1-equiv-1-text-mod-n-for-a-number-n-of-the-form-n)