# Prove that $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} $ for a number $n$ of the form $n = \frac{a^{2p}-1}{a^2-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I want to prove that $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} $ for a number $n$ of the form $n = \frac{a^{2p}-1}{a^2-1}$ with $a \in \mathbb{N}, a \geq2$ and $p$ an odd prime, $p \not \mid a \cdot (a^2-1)$.

I already know that $n$ is not a prime, but I fail to show the identity above. All hints and tips are welcome.

Comment: See theorem $\#89$ of https://archive.org/download/AnIntroductionToTheTheoryOfNumbers-4thEd-G.h.HardyE.m.Wright

Comment: It can't  be proved that $\varphi(n)$ divides $n-1$, because it is false. For $a=2$, $p=5$, we have $n=341$, and $\varphi(341)=300$. Useful only to know what not to try, I'm afraid...

Comment: @ajotatxe The identity above isn't equal to $\varphi(n)$ divides $n-1$, is it?

Comment: No, it isn't. "$\varphi(n)$ divides $n-1$" would be a sufficient condition. But it is false, so there must be another way. The proof of the theorem mentioned by @labbhattacharjee seems to do the job.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The condition for $a^{n-1}  ≡  1 \mod n$ is that $a$ does not divide n and n is odd. Therefore we can write $n- 1 =2p$ then we have:

$a^{2p}-1   ≡ k\cdot\,n$

$k$ must be so that it reduces $a^{2p}-1$ to an integer. Meanwhile $a^{2p}-1=(a^2 -1)[(a^2)^{p-1}+(a^2)^{p-2}+ . . . a^2 + 1]$

Therefore we may write:

$k= a^2 -1$

$ ⇒ n =[(a^2)^{p-1}+(a^2)^{p-2}+ . . . a^2 + 1]$

Which is the reduced form of $\frac{a^{2p}-1}{a^2-1}$ so we may also write:

⇒  $n=\frac{a^{2p}-1}{a^2-1}$

This is a general form and p may be prime or not. The question insist on p to be prime which is a set of primes as the subset of all p.